# How to prevent function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

This is a toy example but it illustrates the point I guess ...
I need to be sure a templated function (can be a class member) is invoked only and only if the argument type is specified, since the specialization will be different for the several chosen types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void ff(T x) { cout << "NO WAY!!! : " << x << endl; }

template<>
void ff(uint16_t x) { cout << "uint16_t thing: " << x << endl; }

template<>
void ff(uint32_t x) { cout << "uint32_t thing: " << x << endl; }

// ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Compiling and running the example, it produces:

```
ff<uint16_t>(10); // -> uint16_t thing: 10

ff(10); // -> NO WAY!!! : 10 ... This is the case I'm trying to avoid ...
```

To forbid the compilation of the second function call I've replaced the first declaration with:

```
template<typename T>
void ff(std::type_identity_t<T> && x) { cout << "NO NO NO! : " << x << endl; }
```

But it fails to compile ...

```
error: template-id ‘ff<>’ for ‘void ff(uint16_t)’ does not match any template declaration
```

(gcc 12.3.0)

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Then why use templates at all?  Why not name your function `ff_uint16` and `ff_uint32`?  The whole point of a template is that the compiler picks the proper function based on the type provided.  If you don't want that, don't use it.

Comment: Specialising template functions is so hard that C++ standard even has a haiku about it. I wouldn't recommend doing that. If I'm not mistaken, all you need is `void ff(auto&& x) = delete;`? This will forbid calling `f` with arguments other than `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, no need to engage in templates (well, not explicitly).

Comment: Is `ff(10u);` supposed to compile if `uint32_t` is `unsigned int`? I.e. do you _really_ want to force explicit template arguments or only avoid implicit conversions?

Comment: Anyway, the error is the `&&` which doesn't belong there. (You don't use pass-by-reference in the other templates and specializations either.) And you'll then need to explicitly specify the template arguments in the explicit specializations as well, e.g. `ff<uint16_t>(uint16_t x)` instead of `ff(uint16_t x)`.

Comment: yes, the && is spurious ;-)  But all your comments contain the answer to the question! I'll put it in the main body of the post ...

Answer (score 4):

---

### How to do it ...

PS: Your comments lead me to the right track!

Of course there's no need to use templates on simple functions, but if we have a class with template member functions it can be handy ;-)

The only missing thing was the template arg type at `ff<T>()` specialization ...

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void ff(std::type_identity_t<T> x) { /* force arg type */ }

template<>
void ff<uint16_t>(uint16_t x) { cout << "uint16_t thing: " << x << endl; }

template<>
void ff<uint32_t>(uint32_t x) { cout << "uint32_t thing: " << x << endl; }
```

Now, let's compile:

```
ff(10)                       // no template arg type -> ERROR
ff<uint16_t>(10);            // Ok! it compiles :-)
```

Yes, I wanted to compiler to give an error if the template type was missing, forcing me to specify it, something it does now.

Thank you all, you've been most helpful!

The terse link to type_traits at cppreference.com is the following:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity